# Thread Template: link error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a linkage error with the following example:

In a file named a.h:

```
namespace n {
class A {
    ...
 public:
  template<class Function, class... Args>
  void a_member(Function &&f, Args &&...args);
 private:
  std::thread *t_;
};
}
```

In A.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"

template<class Function, class... Args>
void n::A::a_member(Function &&f, Args &&...args) {
    this->t_ = new std::thread(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

In a file named B.h:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "c.h" /* declaration of class C */

class B {
 public:
  void b_member1();
  void b_member2(C c);
 private:
  A *a_;
};
```

In B.cpp:

```
#include "B.h"

void B::b_member1() {
    C c;
    this->a_ = new A();
    this->a_->a_member(&B::b_member2, c);
}
```

I'd like to wrap the call to the thread callback with a member function with a parameter of class C.

**EDIT**:

Since the method has been moved in the header, an error still persist: the call to thread constructor seems to be incorrect (signature of function mismatch):

```
this->t_ = new std::thread(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

Comment: I'm not sure on how to solve the problem with the link you provided.

Comment: Move the implementation of `a_member` to the header file

Comment: Thank you, I moved the definition in the header however, I still can not compile. The problem is the call to the thread constructor (the signature doesn't match) `this->t_ = new std::thread(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);`

Comment: You're missing the implicit `this` argument: `this->a_->a_member(&B::b_member2, *this, c);`.

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out.. Too many hours coding... time to have a break. Thank you :)